# Can not fill table inside tab that is displayed as ifram within another JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a simple `login.jsp` and `loginservlet` that check users, if username is correct then open `Main.jsp` page.
`login.jsp` is my default page when run my webapp.
`Main.jsp` has 2 tabs, the second tab use `DocTab.jsp` as **iframe**.
`DocTab.jsp` has a table that fill by a list from `MainServlet`.

When I use `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/MainServlet` the `DocTab.jsp` is displayed and table is filled, but when I run webapp after username and password checking in `login.jsp` the `Main.jsp` is running but second tab (DocTab.jsp) displayed by this **error:**

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because "dataList" is null

[image: error]

**login.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**loginServlet**

```
    package com.example.simplewebapp;
    import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
    import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.io.IOException;
    @WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
    public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            if(username.equals("1") && password.equals("1")) {
                response.sendRedirect("Main.jsp");
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Main.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Main</title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Main Page!</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Document Tab</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="tab1">
        <p>Content for Tab 1.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="tab2">
        <iframe src="DocTab.jsp"></iframe>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**MainServlet**

```
    package com.example.simplewebapp;
    
    import jakarta.servlet.*;
    import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
    import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @WebServlet("/MainServlet")
    public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
            dataList.add("Data 1");
            dataList.add("Data 2");
            dataList.add("Data 3");
            dataList.add("Data 4");
            dataList.add("Data 5");
    
            request.setAttribute("dataList", dataList);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("DocTab.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

**DocTab.jsp**

```
    <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Document Tab</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <table border=1 >
        <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
    
        <% List<String> dataList = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("dataList");
            for(int i=0; i<dataList.size(); i++) { %>
    
        <tr><td><%=dataList.get(i)%></td><td>Row <%=i+1%>, Column 2</td></tr>
    
        <% } %>
    
    </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Simply put DocTab.jsp in WEB-INF to prevent it from being opened directly without that the MainServlet is invoked and then change iframe's URL to point MainServlet instead of DocTab.jsp. See abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: its worked, but another problem is that DocTab.jsp include a modal `<iframe id="revise-docs-iframe" src="ReviseDocs.jsp"></iframe>` when i put in WEB-INF, ReviseDocs.jsp is not accessible. i put ReviseDocs.jsp to WEB-INF too but does not work again.

Comment: i change src of iframe as `<iframe id="revise-docs-iframe" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ReviseDocs.jsp"></iframe>` and its worked. thank you